# Kafka Consumer poll messages with python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, consumer, kafka-python

I have problems with polling messages from Kafka in a Consumer Group. 
My Consumer Object assigns to a given partition with

```
self.ps = TopicPartition(topic, partition )
```

and after that the consumer assigns to that Partition:

```
self.consumer.assign([self.ps])
```

After that I am able to count the messages inside the partition with

```
self.consumer.seek_to_beginning(self.ps)
pos = self.consumer.position(self.ps)
```

and `self.consumer.seek_to_end(self.ps)`
.....

In my topic are over 30000 messages. 
The problem is that I am only get exactly one message.

Consumer Configuration with:
`max_poll_records= 200`
`AUTO_OFFSET_RESET` is earliest

And here is my function with this I am trying to get the messages:

```
 def poll_messages(self):


    data = []

    messages = self.consumer.poll(timeout_ms=6000)


    for partition, msgs in six.iteritems(messages):

        for msg in msgs:

            data.append(msg)

    return data
```

Even if I go to the first available offset before start polling the messages
I get only one message.

```
self.consumer.seek(self.ps, self.get_first_offset())
```

I hope someone can explain me what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Best wishes
Jörn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are misunderstanding max_poll_records - this doesn't mean you will get 200 per poll, just a limit on the most you might get.  You will need to call poll multiple times.  I'd refer you to the docs for simple examples: http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html

I believe a more standard implementation is:

```
for message in self.consumer:
  # do stuff like:
  print(msg)
```

Comment: Unfortunately Nick, I believe your example is a blocking call

Comment: Agreed.  Why do you mention that?  It doesn't affect the polling mechanism does it?  I haven't reviewed the source code.

Comment: What happens is that if there's no message on the queue (nothing to read), the for loop doesn't move.
This isn't a problem as such, but it gives you less flexibility.
"soa"'s code above is using polling, where it will wait on the queue for a few seconds, and then do other things.
I think "soa" was looking for a polling solution.

Comment: It is the blocking code take an example you want to send this data to the socket this will block the code and will only allow to create or open 1 connection.